# Hover, DIV fades in but not out

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumbnail").hover(
        function(){
            $(".overthumb").fadeTo(1000,1).show();
        },
        function(){
            $(".overthumb").fadeTo(1000,0).hide();
        }
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/qCa7a/2/

The code above makes a DIV fade in, but for some reason won't fade out.

Maybe FadeOut isn't the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel has said, you don't need to call `hide()`, however you also don't need to call `show()`.

A side note - you're using the function `fadeTo()` which is mainly used to fade an element to a specific opacity value (i.e. 4%). Seeing as you're just fading the element from 0% - 100% and vice versa, you can use these functions respectively:  `fadeIn()` & `fadeOut()`.

Here's an example of using the above functions:

```
    // Bind the event to the required element
    $('#elementid').hover(
        function(){

            // Call the function on a specific element to fade in
            $('.overthumb').fadeIn(1000);

        },
        function(){

            // Call the opposite function on the same element to fade out
            $(".overthumb").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    );
```

Here are the link to the jQueryAPI document for the following functions: [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) & [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: Just noticed the comments above, was too busy writing my response.

Comment: This answer is more thorough than the one selected. It also has a better choice of functions for the task being implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `hide`.

http://jsfiddle.net/qCa7a/3/

Comment: Don't call show either - fadeTo(1000, 1) is equivalent to .show(1000) so the show isn't needed.

Comment: I suggest put a stop(true,false) to prevent the effects to repeat them self.

Comment: How could I make the second DIV overlay the first?

Comment: The problem I am having is that it seems to confuse the fadein/out process.