# Overlaying DIVS

Tags: jquery, html

I can't seem to get the fadeIn Div to overlay the original DIV without causing issues with the fade. Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/qCa7a/11/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumbnail").hover(
        function(){
            $(".overthumb").stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000);
        },
        function(){
            $(".overthumb").stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Is this related to  your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116213/hover-div-fades-in-but-not-out

Comment: Yea, one of the guys there said start a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put the second `div` inside the first one, effectively causing the "out" to fire correctly.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qCa7a/13/)...hope this helps!

For everyone scared of jsfiddle, here's the idea:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="overthumb" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

...and the accompanying script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumbnail").hover(
        function(){
            $(".overthumb").stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000);
        },
        function(){
            $(".overthumb").stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just put it inside the other div?